# Vector spaces and bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modular-arithmetic

> Let $F_p = Z/pZ$ be the field with p elements for some prime p, and
>   consider the vector space $V = F^3_p$ over $F_p$. Find an ordered basis
>   for V containing the element $(1; 1; 1)$.

How does one go about finding a basis for an arbitrary modulo vector space?

Comment: I don't think the process would be that different from $\mathbf{R}$. How would you answer the question if $F_p$ were replaced with $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: To continue what user180040 is saying, just pick two elements of $F_p^3$ $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ such that $\{(1,1,1),\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ is linearly independent. If you're having trouble finding such elements, just think about the standard basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: So I must find 3 linearly independent vectors, for example (1,1,1);(1,0,1);(0,1,1)?

Comment: You could make it simpler than that, too. In the end, you need to make sure the vectors are linearly independent. One way you can do that is by calculating the determinant (although if the vectors you've picked are simple enough, this may be overkill). For example, if the determinant is $50$, then your vectors will work if and only if $p \ne 2,5$. Alternatively, show that all three vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$ are in the span of the three you've chosen.

Comment: @user180040 I have calculated my determinant as -1, does this mean the 3 vectors I have chosen are not only linearly independent, but they will also work for all primes?

Comment: @user43290 yes.

Comment: Yes, that's right, as user43290 said. But it's also good to see these ways of doing it: (1) set up the equations that would show that the set is linearly independent, straight from the definition of linear independence; (2) show that the three standard basis vectors are in the span of your three, so the three you've chosen are a generating set.

Answer (score 1):

An easier set of vectors to work with is $(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

In order to show that the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \Bbb F^3$ are linearly independent, it suffices to show that the matrix $(v_1 ,v_2,v_3)$ is nonsingular.  Try taking the determinant.